# Tesseract tsv output not working

Tags: csv, tesseract, ubuntu-17.10

I'm trying to execute tesseract from command line in Ubuntu 17.10. I want the output in a `.tsv` file because I need the confidence rate. As explained [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage#tsv-output-currently-available-in-305-dev-in-master-branch-on-github), I execute:

```
tesseract testing_img.png out tsv
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
read_params_file: Can't open tsv
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.00 with Leptonica
```

and the output is written correctly in a `out.txt` file. It seems that it reads that `tsv` parameter as a file to read, but I don't know why.

I've compiled Tesseract from source because I need Tesseract 3.05 in order to have a `.tsv` file as output, so I can't use the version in the Ubuntu repository because it has Tesseract 3.04.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10.

Here's some information about my Tesseract installation:

```
$ tesseract --version
    tesseract 3.05.00
     leptonica-1.75.3
      libpng 1.6.34 : zlib 1.2.11

$ ls /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/
    configs  eng.traineddata  ita.traineddata  osd.traineddata  pdf.ttf  tessconfigs

$ echo $TESSDATA_PREFIX
    /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, in my case a file called `tsv` in the directory

```
/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/configs
```

is missing. I downloaded the source code of tesseract from:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/archive/3.05.00.tar.gz

and replaced the content of the folder `configs`.

Comment: That config file is a shortcut for `-c tessedit_create_tsv=1`